# Problem with SQL query when calling a static function from another static function in the same class

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm new to PHP, but not new to programming. I have a strange problem. It's such a simple thing, and I have the feeling the solution is simple also, but I tried for hours without luck.

I have a model class User which contains the following function:

```
public static function byUsername($username) {
    $row = DB::fetchOne('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?', $username);
    if (!is_null($row)) {
        return new User($row);
    }
    return null;
}
```

It works as expected everywhere, returning a User object given the right username. Except in the User class itself: when I call the function with `User::byUsername('a_valid_username')`, or `self::`, from another static function further down in the User class, the `DB::fetchOne()` function just returns `null`, no errors or exceptions.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a problem inside of the `byUsernam()` method.

Perform

```
echo $username;
```

or

```
print_r( debug_backtrace() );
```

right at the beginning of `byUsernam()` to learn more of the called environment.

Comment: `echo` or `var_dump` don't work in there, but `error_log` does. `$username` is set, and `debug_backtrace` looks good too.